# Meiomask - unable to apply setMask to controls in ASP

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, meiomask

I am trying use [this jQuery mask input plugin](https://github.com/fabiomcosta/jquery-meiomask) that will force users to enter alphanumeric values, a period and a space.

I am trying to allow alphanumeric(10 bytes) with the statement below.

```
$('#CommentsTextBox').setMask({ mask: '****' });
```

However, it does not allow any user input. I am applying inputmasks to other controls on my page just fine.

If I comment out this statement then I can enter values.

Here is the the code for the control in the `.aspx`

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="CommentsPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="CommentsTextBox" CssClass="longTextBox" runat="server" MaxLength="150" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="4" ClientIDMode="Static" />
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Comment: ' $('#CommentsTextBox').setMask({ mask: '**********' });'

Comment: What plug-in are you talking about? The first one that shows up in Google, [Igor Escobar's](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) uses a different syntax. You should also post the relevant HTML.

Comment: I am using: fabiomcosta  / jquery-meiomask plugin, setmask function. Below is code in external .js file used by site.

Comment: 'masks: {
       'phone': { mask: '(99) 9999-9999' },
      'phone-us': { mask: '(999) 999-9999' },
      'cpf': { mask: '999.999.999-99' }, 
      'cnpj': { mask: '99.999.999/9999-99' },
      'date': { mask: '39/19/9999' }, //uk date
      'date-us': { mask: '19/39/9999' },
      'cep': { mask: '99999-999' },
      'time': { mask: '29:59' },
      'cc': { mask: '9999 9999 9999 9999' }, //credit card mask'

Comment: Can't seem to post it correctly here. Basically there is a setmask function that can be called by another external .js file that enables mask on textbox. Didn't dig deep enough before initial question. Must be something about this textbox that is different than rest. Here is ASPX:

Comment: <asp:PlaceHolder ID="CommentsPlaceHolder" runat="server">
 <asp:TextBox ID="CommentsTextBox" CssClass="longTextBox" runat="server" MaxLength="150" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="4" ClientIDMode="Static" />
</asp:PlaceHolder>

Comment: When you need to add further details please **edit** the question and post the relevant info there. Code in comments is unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gKuaH/13/) demonstrating usage, I included a `textarea` since that is what your control will be rendered as.

The reason it's not working for you is because you're using the wrong ID.

There are 3 different types of IDs in ASP. [(you can find more info here)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d04y8ss%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX)

> 1. ID — this is the ID you specify in markup or by setting the control's ID property.
> 2. UniqueID — this is an ID that is generated by ASP.NET for use by code that runs on the server.
> 3. ClientID — this is an ID that is generated by ASP.NET for use by client code (it is rendered as the value of the id attribute in HTML).

Note #3, this is the property you need to use in order to access the ID of the rendered control.

In your case, the rendered ID of your `textbox` will probably look something like this..

```
<textarea ID='CommentsPlaceHolder?CommentsTextBox' />
```

The reason this isn't working for you, is because you have no controls with an ID of `CommentsTextBox`

A common practice is to do something like this..

```
var Members =
{
    CommentsTextBox: $("#<%=CommentsTextBox.ClientID %>"),
    StartDateCalendarText: $('#<%=StartDateCalendarText.ClientID %>') 
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    Members.CommentsTextBox.setMask({ 'mask': '**********' });
    Members.StartDateCalendarText.setMask({ 'mask': '99/99/9999' });
});
```

Comment: Hey Kevin, thanks for response. This is throwing a Javascript error. Also, the jquery line below works fine for validating date textbox. Also, I will attempt to include ASPX for comment box.

Comment: $('#StartDateCalendarText').setMask({ mask: '99/99/9999' });

Comment: <asp:PlaceHolder ID="CommentsPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="CommentsTextBox" CssClass="longTextBox"    runat="server" MaxLength="150" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="4" ClientIDMode="Static" />
</asp:PlaceHolder>

Comment: ?    <asp:TextBox ID="CommentsTextBox" CssClass="longTextBox" runat="server"  MaxLength="10" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="4"  ClientIDMode="Static" />

Comment: @KentE No, the multiline setting just means that the control will be rendered as a `<textarea>` rather than an `<input>`.  The mask will work on either one, as long as you are applying it correctly.

Comment: @KentE I added this new control to my post, just be sure you're accessing the appropriate Id and it should work for you.  I also updated my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gKuaH/14/

Comment: @KentE if you're still having problems you need to edit your original post and show us some code